# Xcode 6 reverted my storyboard to a previous state automatically

Tags: storyboard, xcode6

Let's say I had an storyboard in state A when the app was in development, state B is the version on the App store.

After submitting the app to the App store, I didn't change my storyboard; I opened my storyboard this morning and it was in state B, then I made a few changes to other parts of the project, now when I open the storyboard, instead of state B, I see state A!

If this is just an annoying bug, it is making me mad, because these two states A and B are so different, I need to spend days to reproduce B :(
I tried relaunching Xcode, but it didn't help. Restoring via time machine didn't help either, nor does restoring the project to a previous snapshot, it is as if B has just disappeared from my computer!

Comment: Provide more details, like how much different they were. Things just don't disappear randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Xcode assigned the old scheme to the project (It probably happened after renaming a few things), I changed it and it is working now.